# HTML Autocomplete (or Emmet or ZenCoding) in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise does not work when editing JSX. (NOT VS Code)

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, visual-studio-2019, jsx, emmet

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise, in HTML files the "emmet" functionality works fine.

But in React projects, when I want to write JSX codes it does not work.

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same issue. Zen coding worked every where except in react projects.

**First Solution:**

I changed file format as `js` to `jsx` and it solved my problem.

**Second Solution:**

If you don't want to change format, alter file language mode to `jsx`. Click at right bottom corner:

[image]

Comment: Can you add another line vs changing it to jsx? so then you can have them both working?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not realize your comment @daddycardona

Comment: What I a was trying to say is that you changed it from js to jsx, could you have written another line and included both js and jsx?
@seyed mohammad asghari

Comment: I added another solution that it doesn't need the file format  and just file mode is enough. I hope it works for you @daddycardona

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a solution.

The solution is by including javascriptReact language in emmet extension.

And that is done in the 'setting.json' file,

And then add the following code.

```
  -----previous setting--- ,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Don't forget comma(,) before the previous setting.

Comment: Thanks bro, but are you sure you are talking about VS 2019 and not VS Code? How can I find this JSON in VS 2019?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a Visual Studio extension like [ZenCoding](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ZenCoding), there isn't much you can do.  That extension registers its commands to run on [certain](https://github.com/madskristensen/ZenCodingVS/blob/6eda51796871c16c533283727f338d602cdb6d74/src/Commands/CommandRegistration.cs#L13) document types - or content types in VS parlance (in this case, HTML and HTMLX which are for the ASPX and HTML editors respectively).  JSX files, however, use the TypeScript content type, so the ZenCoding extension is never invoked on JSX documents.

One possible option would be to build your own copy of the extension, adding the appropriate content type. (Note: You'll probably have to modify other parts of the code as well, such as [this method](https://github.com/madskristensen/ZenCodingVS/blob/6eda51796871c16c533283727f338d602cdb6d74/src/Commands/ExpandCommand.cs#L88).)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be a reasonable solution. But wouldn't it better to totally switch to VS Code instead?

Comment: That's totally subjective.  VS and VS Code offer very different development experiences, but if VS Code works for you, then sure.

Answer (score 0):

In Html file in Visual Studio 2019 or 2022 Preview right click-> insert Snippet->html5

Does same thing as Emmet in VS Code.

Comment: what snippet are you talking about?

Comment: I see what you trying to say but they are not asking for that. They are asking if you can make a class .card turn into <div class="card"> for JSX file. What sucks without zen which was freezing my stuff with its update just now